# Sort integers and strings using the same java class (Bubble Sort)

Tags: java, string, class, sorting, bubble-sort

How do I amend my code for bubble sorting integers so I can re-use it for strings too? Or do I need to create a completely new class for sorting strings exclusively. Thanks!

**MAIN CLASS**:

```
public class BubbleSortTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] integers = {25, 15, 45, 5, 40, 50, 10, 20, 35, 30};
        ArrayUtility.display(integers);
        BubbleSort.sort(integers);
        ArrayUtility.display(integers);

        String[] strings = {"def", "efg", "bcd", "abc", "fgh", "cde", null};
        ArrayUtility.display(strings);
        BubbleSort.sort(strings);
        ArrayUtility.display(strings);
    }
}
```

**SORT CLASS:**

```
public class BubbleSort {

    public static void sort(Integer[] numbers) {
        Integer temp;

        for (Integer i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            for (Integer j = 1; j < (numbers.length) - i; j++) {
                if (numbers[j - 1] > numbers[j]) {

                    //SWAPPING ELEMENTS
                    temp = numbers[j - 1];
                    numbers[j - 1] = numbers[j];
                    numbers[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: google 'Java generics', or, pass type 'Comparable' or similar

Comment: Look at how it's done in e.g. [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet(java.util.Comparator)). (Generics + Comparator)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html):

Something like this could be valid:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void bubbleSort(E[] unsorted) {
        for(int iter =1; iter< unsorted.length; iter++){
            for(int inner = 0; inner < (unsorted.length - iter); inner ++){
                if(unsorted[inner].compareTo(unsorted[inner+1]) > 0){
                    E tmp = unsorted[inner];
                    unsorted[inner] = unsorted[inner + 1];
                    unsorted[inner + 1] = tmp;
                }                
            }
        }
    }
```

What this means is, the method works with an array of any type, as long as it implements `Comparable`. Whatever type that is, will be used as `E` throughout the method. Since the compiler knows that `E` is a `Comparable`, the compiler knows that objects of this type have `.compareTo(...)`.

Comment: `<E extends Comparable<E>>` and the cast is not needed and all safe.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing to use what @JoopEggen correctly suggested.

Comment: Very good answer, but I wouldn't call the argument 'unsorted' because it doesn't stay unsorted for long.